# Observable rotation screen

Tags: java, observable

I use RealmObject with Observable lib for load data from server.
This is my method in ListFragment:

```
@Override
public void loadMore() {
    super.loadMore();
    mSubscription = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<RealmCase>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<RealmCase>> subscriber) {
            Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getActivity());
            PojoGetCasesParams params = FiltersHelper.getInstance()
                    .getCasesParams(page, PAGE_LIMIT);
            if (page == 0) {
                realm.beginTransaction();
                try {
                    GetCaseTypesResult result = KleoService.getInstance().loadCasesBaseData();
                    for (CaseType t : result.data) {
                        RealmCaseType realmCaseType = t.toRealmObject();
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(realmCaseType);
                    }
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    realm.cancelTransaction();
                }
            }

            realm.beginTransaction();
            try {
                if (isLastCase) {
                    result = KleoService.getInstance().loadLastCasesData();
                } else {
                    result = KleoService.getInstance().loadCasesData(params);
                }
                List<RealmCase> cases = new ArrayList<>();
                for (WKMobCaseDO caseDO : result) {
                    RealmCase realmCase = caseDO.toRealmObject();
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(realmCase);
                    cases.add(realmCase);
                }
                realm.commitTransaction();
                subscriber.onNext(cases);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                realm.cancelTransaction();
                e.printStackTrace();
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
            realm.close();
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this);
}
```

The SuperClass BaseListFragment set adapter and show progress dialog for refresh my contents ui:

```
protected void loadMore() {
    if (mAdapter != null && !mAdapter.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.message_loading), false, false);
}
```

I wish that the screen rotation data is not reloaded.

Any idea?